# How to boot Linux Mint from USB drive via Grub2

Tags: linux, linux-mint, live-usb, initramfs, persistence

I am trying to install Linux Mint Cinnamon 64 bit on a USB drive so I have a portable desktop wit persistence. I am trying to do this manually because I haven't fount a program that does this successfully. I installed Grub2 without problems. My menuentry for Mint is:

```
menuentry "Linux Mint" {
set isofile="/boot/isos/linuxmint-17.2-cinnamon-64bit.iso"

loopback loop $isofile
linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz iso_filename=$isofile
initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz
}
```

When I boot from the USB Stick, I reach a terminal environment where the user is `Initramfs` a Toshiba Satellite C55Dt-A5106, 12GB RAM, AMD A6 APU

Comment: Did you try with UNetbootin?

Comment: Yes, when I try to set persistence, the x server (GUI) doesn't start.

Comment: @migrc sorry I forgot to mention you